# How to use history pushstate

Tags: javascript, back-button

I used `history.pushstate` to modify the URL content, which was a better AJAX solution for me, when the task was completed, I got this method from [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/VF9jZ/show/html5/html5#). Now, I want to clear the URL after certain task are completed. What am I supposed to do in order to clear the modified URL back into the original URL?

Comment: save it and then later pushstate() it again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.history.pushState("","", "heyIJustChangedMyUrlWithoutPosting");
```

Links (included SO threads and external articles) available [here](http://andrealigios.blogspot.it/2012/09/html5-change-url-without-reloading-page.html)

Comment: i wanted to say, it changed the url from {url} to "heyIJustChangedMyUrlWithoutPosting" but i want the url to be back to {url} which was at the beginning

Comment: Sorry didn't get the problem, and still don't get it completely... pushState avoids the needs of using POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern, what you are pushing is already the new URL...
by the way, you can save your previous url to a variable, and do a new pushState() with your previous URL...