# Hiding URLs from the location bar

Tags: javascript, jsp, url, tomcat, gwt

This might be a silly question which I'll delete if I realise, so if you are reading this then I didn't yet figure it out.

I have some software which is online (addressable) and available but it's a bit of a secret, so instead of just hitting my software when you come to my domain, you are shown a blog that I wrote and hidden within that blog is a link ;)

### All well and good.

Now the problem is that users of my software always post screenshots which gives my 1/2 secret URL away. EEEEK yep!  So I wanted to have the url be just the plain old normal domain, so as not to make things too easy for them hacky types :p

I have full control over everything here. Clientside / Server / Everything.  Initially you hit some jsp and then the GWT app (inside of Tomcat) - you have to provide login details in the GWT app.  So I have plenty of places to do this URL hiding / faking but any ideas to help would be great.

...and yes I'm posting this (perhaps isn't too dumb)!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use history pushstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029493/how-to-use-history-pushstate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the javascript [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) here

```
history.pushState({},"Some title here","/")
```

For example, on http://yourwebsite.com/secretlink.html, after the JS runs, the URL bar will show http://yourwebsite.com/ *without having refreshed the page*<sup>1</sup>. Note that if the user refreshes the page they will be taken to http://yourwebsite.com/ and not back to the secret link.

You can also do something like `history.pushState({},"Some title here","/hidden.jsp")`, so that if the user refreshes the page you can show them an error page that tells them to find the secret link and open it again.

<sup>1. If you `pushState()` some other domain than your own, a refresh will happen so this cannot be abused to phish sites</sup>

Comment: I'm giving the answer to you.  I'm not testing but you sound right.  I figured I could do this via GWT or on the server.  I've actually decided to go the opposite way and I force everyone to tweet the URL now.  Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: This worked great BTW - so simple too, you deserve the 50 points history.pushState ;)

Comment: UPDATE:  I'm using history.replaceState(...); as history.pushState(...); leaves a history of the secret URL replaceState doesn't (top stuff)

Answer (score -1):

Include the inner page as an iFrame

Comment: yep I could do that but wanted something more serverside

Comment: ...and I tested using an iframe but because my app is a mobile web app using MGWT the iframe affects things badly!

Comment: You want server side then you're going to have to use a proxy server

Comment: its ok its just such a minor thing I can get away with using a one line bit of javascript "history.pushState"